# Segfault when mysql_stmt_close

Tags: mysql, c, linux, segmentation-fault, prepared-statement

I'm trying to query mysql 5.5 using C API.
dbutil.c contains boilerplate code:

```
#include "../include/dbutil.h"
#include "../include/logging.h"
#include "../include/common.h"

MYSQL get_connection(char *host, char *user, char *passwd, char *db) {
    MYSQL conn;
    mysql_init(&conn);
    if (!mysql_real_connect(&conn, host, user, passwd, db, 0, NULL, 0)) {
        log_to_console("Cannot connect to MySQL server: %s", mysql_error(&conn));
        exit(1);
    }
    return conn;
}

MYSQL_STMT prepare_stmt(MYSQL *conn, char *sql) {
    MYSQL_STMT *stmtP = mysql_stmt_init(conn);
    if (!stmtP) {
        log_to_console("Cannot create statement, out of memory.");
        exit(1);
    }

    MYSQL_STMT stmt = *stmtP;

    if (mysql_stmt_prepare(&stmt, sql, strlen(sql))) {
        log_to_console("Preparing statement failed: %s", mysql_error(conn));
        exit(1);
    }

    return stmt;
}

void bind_param(MYSQL_BIND *param, enum enum_field_types fieldType, char* buffer, my_bool *isNull, unsigned long *length) {
    param->buffer_type = fieldType;
    param->buffer = buffer;
    param->is_null = isNull;
    param->length = length;
}

void bind_string_param(MYSQL_BIND *param, int stringSize, char* buffer, my_bool *isNull, unsigned long *length) {
    bind_param(param, MYSQL_TYPE_STRING, buffer, isNull, length);
    param->buffer_length = stringSize;
}

void bind_result(MYSQL_BIND *result, enum enum_field_types fieldType, char* buffer, my_bool *isNull, unsigned long *length) {
    bind_param(result, fieldType, buffer, isNull, length);
}

void bind_string_result(MYSQL_BIND *result, int stringSize, char* buffer, my_bool *isNull, unsigned long *length) {
    bind_string_param(result, stringSize, buffer, isNull, length);
}
```

Here's the code that actually runs the query:

```
#include "../include/dbutil.h"

int main() {
    MYSQL conn = get_connection("localhost", "user", "pass", "test");
    MYSQL_STMT stmt = prepare_stmt(&conn, "SELECT hostname from hosts where id = ?");
    MYSQL_BIND param[1], result[1];

    memset(param, 0, sizeof(param));
    memset(result, 0, sizeof(result));

    int in = 1;
    unsigned long length = 200;
    my_bool isNull[2];
    isNull[0] = 0;

    char out[200];
    bind_param(&param[0], MYSQL_TYPE_LONG, (char *) &in, &isNull[0], (unsigned long *)0);
    bind_string_result(&result[0], 200, (char *) &out, &isNull[1], &length);

    mysql_stmt_bind_param(&stmt, param);
    mysql_stmt_execute(&stmt);
    mysql_stmt_bind_result(&stmt, result);
    mysql_stmt_store_result(&stmt);
    mysql_stmt_fetch(&stmt);

    printf("Restult %s\n", out);

    mysql_stmt_close(&stmt);
    mysql_close(&conn);

    return 0;
}
```

Statement executes and returns the expected result, but the code segfaults when it hits

```
mysql_stmt_close(&stmt);
```

I've poked around the core dump and found that segfault is caused by libc free() statement, which I presume is called in free_root() in libmysql.c, in

```
my_bool STDCALL mysql_stmt_close(MYSQL_STMT *stmt)
{
  MYSQL *mysql= stmt->mysql;
  int rc= 0;
  DBUG_ENTER("mysql_stmt_close");

  free_root(&stmt->result.alloc, MYF(0));
  free_root(&stmt->mem_root, MYF(0));
  free_root(&stmt->extension->fields_mem_root, MYF(0));
...
```

to be specific. Core dump says that *stmt.extension is  when statement closing occurs. Any ideas why is that so?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the code / library is trying to `free()` some memory that has already been released.

After some googling, I found [this link.](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=73) It would appear that you should check to make sure `stmt` isn't NULL before calling `mysql_stmt_close()`. If `stmt` is already NULL, the library already cleaned it up and it won't be necessary to call `mysql_stmt_close()`.

Answer (score 1):

Check at the out parameter here:

```
char out[200];
...
bind_string_result(&result[0], 200, (char *) &out, &isNull[1], &length);
```

If you see your bind_string_result declaration:

```
void bind_string_result(MYSQL_BIND *result, int stringSize, char* buffer, my_bool *isNull, unsigned long *length) {
```

The function is expecting to receive a parameter of type `char *` while you are sending a pointer to a `char *`, in other words a `char **`

The compiler is not giving you any warning since you are casting the parameter to `char *` but it may create conflicts in your memory.  Try to invoke you function as:

```
bind_string_result(&result[0], 200, out, &isNull[1], &length);
```

Comment: The problem is actually with mysql_init(&conn).
For some reason, conn does not get initialized. If I initialize conn and pass it to get_connection everything works as expected.